# Compare Three Values in NlogN

Tags: algorithm

How does one take an Array, and compare three values in the array, without comparing the values more than once.

I can iterate with three nested loops, but that will result in the same inner block being called three times. I want NlogN time.

```
For Loop
    For Loop
        For Loop
            add values and store if greater than max
```

Comment: Looking at the line "add values and store if greater than max" makes me wonder - why not just sort the array and add the largest 3 values?

Comment: Can you clarify somewhat what you are trying to accomplish here? Comparing three values of an array? To each other? Which three values? What do you want as the result of the operation?

Comment: what do you mean 'compare 3 values'? are you looking for the highest sum of 3 numbers? just find the 3 biggest, it is O(n)

Comment: I just added that for simplicity. I guess I shouldn't have. What actually happens is a function call where the order of the values doesn't matter.

check_for_validity(A,B,C)

Comment: I am trying to take three values, and see if they are compatible with each other.

Comment: @Matt: Compatible!? What does that mean?!

Comment: Do you have some numberic value for comparison? for instance, finding 3 numbers in an array that sums to a constant can be done in O(n^2)

Comment: @Matt Helm - Are you saying that you need to pass every permutation of 3 array elements to your check_for_validity function?

Comment: comparing 3 values is O(1). You haven't been able to formulate your problem!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I quite follow the question, but what you may want is to do something like this:

```
for i from 1 to N {
    for j from i+1 to N {
        for k from j+1 to N {
            if (i+j+k > currentMax) {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea if that is what he's trying to achieve, but it definetly doesn't satisfy complexity constraint

Comment: @amit: His complexity constraint made no sense to me, so I focused on the non-redundancy aspect of comparing every triple of values.

Comment: @PengOne; Your algorithm seems to be `O(n^3)`.

Comment: @ypercube Yes. See my comment above.